# Dynamic Progress Bar Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an object :

```
myObj = [
{
    word_id : "...",
    sub_word : {
       "attr1" : "....",
       "attr2" : "....",
    },
    "level" : 0
},
{
    word_id : "...",
    sub_word : {
       "attr1" : "....",
       "attr2" : "....",
    },
    "level" : 1
},
{
    word_id : "...",
    sub_word : {
       "attr1" : "....",
       "attr2" : "....",
    },
    "level" : 2
},
.
.
.
.]
```

And i have three progress bars, to display the % of every word dependeing on it's level. For example, if `myObj` contains 17 words : 13 words with level 2, 2 words with level 1 and 2 words with level 0. the three progress bars will be respectively filled with CSS/JS, using the number of words for each level multiplied by 10. To do that, I wrote something like :

```
$(".progressBar").css("height", numberOfWords*10 + '%');
```

The problem here is, if i ever have more than 10 words with a certain level, the progress bar will be completely filled, because the calculated height will be 100% of the progress bar.

Is there any way to make the progress bar dynamically depending on `myObj` length ?

Comment: You have to set the progress bar heights separately, if you want them to be different. I'm not really understanding why you would want the progress bar to be different heights, or based on words, though. Do tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can work out the percentages like this: (the levels match your example)

```js
var words = [
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "Never" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "Gonna" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "Give" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "You" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "Up" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "Never" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "Gonna" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "Let" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "You" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "Down" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "Never" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "Gonna" },
  { "level": 2, "word_id": "Run" },
  { "level": 0, "word_id": "Around" },
  { "level": 0, "word_id": "And" },
  { "level": 1, "word_id": "Desert" },
  { "level": 1, "word_id": "You" }
];

var levels = [...new Set(words.map(a => a.level))]
levels.sort();

for (var level of levels) {
  var wordsPerLevel = words.filter(a => a.level == level).length;
  var percentage = Math.round((wordsPerLevel/words.length)*100);
  console.log("Level " + level + ": " + percentage + "%");
}
```

That will show the percentage for every level that is contained in the `words` array. Levels will be sorted.